# How to use NIO and JFilechooser in Java 7?

Tags: java, nio

I am using Java 7, `NIO` package rather than `IO`, but JFileChooser uses `File` class to `getSelectedFile()`, but in NIO there is only `Path` class. How can I use `NIO` classes with `JFileChooser` ?

Comment: You're better off start with the official [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html). It's easy to follow and provides a lot of useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Path path = selectedFile.toPath();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
yourPath = yourJFileChooser.getSelectedFile().toPath();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
File file = Paths.get(URI).toFile();
```